# Jetpack Compose screen labeling for accessibility

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to label a screen for accessibility when using `Jetpack Compose`?
Getting the following error:

*This item may not have a label readable by screen readers.*

from the google play pre-launch report for all my app screens, cant see where you can 'tag' composables with content meta data.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow the [accessibility guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility#semantics). Basically, the Semantics modifier will let you add content descriptions to composables. Something like:

```
Modifier.semantics {
    this.contentDescription = "Custom content description" }
)
```

Note: The call for `Modifier.semantics()` should be invoked from within the component itself. It is not meant to be added to the modifiers stack passed along as a function argument.

Comment: Hi, where did you place the `semantics` modifier ? On the top most composable ?